Many-body wave function using Bloch Form
I have a crystalline system of lattice constant $a$ and periodic boundary condition is imposed over $M$ linear cells and there are $M $ equally spaced Bloch vectors in the reciprocal cell $[0,\frac{2\pi}{a}]$
i.e. $$q_s = \frac{2\pi}{Ma}s$$  where s= 0,1,2...M-1
The size of the periodically repeated system is $L ­=Ma$ and the one-body orbitals can be chosen to have the Bloch form
i.e. $$\psi_{q_s,m}(x+\tau)= e^{iq_s \tau} \psi_{q_s,m}(x)$$
with $\tau = la$ being the lattice translation and $m$ is the band index.
Now there are $\frac{N}{M}$ occupied bands in the Slater determinant wave function, which can be written as,
$$|\Psi_0\rangle = A \prod_{m=1}^{N/M} \prod_{s=0}^{M-1} \psi_{q_s, m}$$
where A is the antisymmetrizer and N being number of particles.
My question is, How this expression of Slater determinant can be derived and what does it mean by $\frac{N}{M}$ occupied bands?

Mixing kets and functions in the last equation is probably a mistake (or a very weird notation)... Furthermore, this doe snot look as a Slater determinant at all, but as a product wave function (of which a Slater-liek sum can be composed.) Perhaps, the Q. misses some elements - could you cite the text where it comes from?

@RogerV. it is not a mistake; you can see equation 14 of https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9709306

Ah, I overlooked that $A$ is the antisymmetrizer. Do you imagine how the expression for a determinant looks like (not the formal matrix description, but the actual result)?

@RogerV. Unfortunately, I have no idea about it :(

You study quantum mechanics without having learned linear algebra? Not your fault... but it promises many unpleasant surprizes in future.

You have N particles, and each band can keep M particles, so there will be N/M bands filled, the rest being empty. Isn't that reasonable?

The crucial point here is the operator $A$, which is called antisymmetrizer (the question is based on this article.) In other words, this operator performs all the possible permutations of indices (or variables) in the product wave function that follows it, to form a proper Slater determinant. E.g., for two functions in a product this would mean:
$$
A\left[\psi(x)\phi(y)\right]=\psi(x)\phi(y)-\phi(x)\psi(y).
$$
More general determinant can be written in terms of Levi-Civita symbol as:
$$
det(X)=\sum_{i_1, i_2, ..., i_n}\varepsilon_{i_1 i_2...i_n}x_{1i_1}x_{2i_2}...x_{ni_n},
$$
so that the antisymmetrizer for wave function of $n$ particles is
$$
A\left[\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)...\phi_n(x_n)\right]=
\sum_{i_1, i_2, ..., i_n}\varepsilon_{i_1 i_2...i_n}\phi_1(x_{i_1})\phi_2(x_{i_2})...\phi_n(x_{i_n})=\\
\sum_{i_1, i_2, ..., i_n}\varepsilon_{i_1 i_2...i_n}\phi_{i_1}(x_1)\phi_{i_2}(x_2)...\phi_{i_n}(x_n)
$$
